# YAML: When an equals sign (=) can be used for dictionaries?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I read `key1=value1 key2=value2` style dictionaries all the time in ansible playbooks that are supposed to be written in YAML. On the other hand I didn't find any documentation for this format and there seem to be cases where it doesn't work for me. What is the exact specification and where can I find it?

Comment: You cannot do this *in YAML*, as it is not in the specification of YAML. But you can of course have an `=` in a non-quoted scalar string. How an application interprets that string once loaded, has nothing to do with YAML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible syntax best practice, YAML dictionary (key: value) or equal sign (key=value)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822354/ansible-syntax-best-practice-yaml-dictionary-key-value-or-equal-sign-key-va)

Answer (score 6):

In Ansible `key=value` is not used for dicts in general.

It is an alternative syntax to pass parameters to actions/modules, like:

```
- name: restart apache
  service: name=apache state=restarted
```

Here you pass `name` and `state` parameters to `service` module.

From YAML perspective `name=apache state=restarted` is a string. There's some magic done under the hood by Ansible to split it. But it become unreliable and cumbersome with complex arguments, so I always use native YAML syntax:

```
- name: restart apache
  service:
    name: apache
    state: restarted
```

And this `key=value` works only for modules/actions parameters, you can't define dictionaries like this:

```
vars:
  # this will give you a string, not dict
  mydict: key1=value1 key2=value
```