# Creating a directory with Ansible results in file ownership change in /usr/lib/python3.7

Tags: ansible

Using Ubuntu 19.04 and Python 3.7

When I create a directory with Ansible, file ownership is changed in /usr/lib/python3.7

Obviously this should not happen and it breaks Python for the whole of Ubuntu, until the permissions are corrected.

The problem ***only happens when recurse=yes*** is used.

Here is a video showing the problem: 
https://youtu.be/d3hj255pW9w

Here is the code/Ansible playbook:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~/ansible$ cat ~/ansible/renderworker/ffmpegconverter/ansible/test.yml
---
- hosts: renderworkerhosts
  become: yes

  tasks:

    # for some reason, recurse=yes results in owner & permissions changing in /usr/lib/python3.7
    # which breaks Python on Ubuntu

    - name: Create directory
      file:
        path=/opt/ffmpegconverter
        state=directory
        owner=root
        group=ffmpeguser
        mode=u=rwx,g=rwx,o=
        recurse=yes

ubuntu@ubuntu-GB-BXi3-5010:~/ansible$
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a colon instead of the equal sign for delimiter between keys and values:

```
path: /etc/foo.conf
```

Comment: Could you explain more please.  Are you saying this is the problem?  Is it a requirement or a preference to use colon?  Most of my ansible scripts seems to work using equal sign - are they wrong?  thanks!!

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907723/yaml-when-an-equals-sign-can-be-used-for-dictionaries . In short for complex parameters it is unreliable to use equal signs.

Comment: and i don't know if it is the problem

Comment: Not happening to me with ubuntu 18.04 and debian 9 hosts (run from Fedora 30 and Ansible 2.8.1), just to make sure try to change the delimiters to `:` as suggested, another option is to debug the produced python code by `export ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1`