# how to escape single quotes in ansible variables registered during execution. I cannot use "\" since the variable is unknown until its registered

Tags: ansible

When a registered variable has a single quote in it, for example
if value of `var.stdout` is `IxMy5NPG'dCbrHD` (**note the single quote in string**)

When I use this variable in an upcoming task,

```
lineinfile:
  path: /path/to/file.j2 
  regexp: "X1234" 
  line: {{ var.stdout }} 
  mode: 0755 
  state: present
```

I get the follwing error

```
ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced 
jinja2 block or quotes
```

This only occurs if there is a single quote in the string, which may or may not have a single quote. Hence I cannot expect this already and handle it. I tried a regex_replace filter on the variable like `{{ var.stdout | regex_replace("'", "\'") }}`  I get "Unexpected failure during module execution."

Comment: Please, for the love of your own sanity, do not mix the `key=value` and YAML `key: value` syntaxes. To read further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39823977/2123530

Comment: Syntax is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `{{ var.stdout }}` must be quoted

```yaml
lineinfile:
  path: file.j2 
  regexp: X1234
  line: {{ var.stdout }}  # <-- WRONG
```

For example, given the file

```
shell> cat file.j2
X1234
```

The task below

```yaml
lineinfile:
  path: file.j2 
  regexp: X1234
  line: "{{ var.stdout }}"  # <-- CORRECT
```

works as expected

```
shell> cat file.j2
IxMy5NPG'dCbrHD
```

---

If you want to replace the quote for example with the underscore "_"

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        var_stdout: "{{ var.stdout|regex_replace(_regex, _replace) }}"
      vars:
        _regex: "'"
        _replace: "_"
```

gives

```yaml
  var_stdout: IxMy5NPG_dCbrHD
```

To avoid escaping put _regex/_replace into the task's vars.

---

If you want to escape the quote

```yaml
        _replace: "\\'"
```

gives

```yaml
  var_stdout: IxMy5NPG\'dCbrHD
```